# show new info on list click PHP

Tags: php

I have a PHP page that creates list-elements when a form is submited, the form sends 5 values to a text-file then the two first values of the form is sent back and displayed in a list element, looks like this:

```
$myFile = 'demo.txt';
$content = file($myFile);
$content_array = explode("/n", $content);

<ul id="list">
<?php 
for($i = 0; $i < count($content_array); $i++){
  $values = explode(';', $content_array[$i]);
  $titel = $values[0];
  $grade = $values[1];
  $link = $values[2];
  $pic = $values[3];
  $desc = $values[4];            
  echo '<li">'.$titel.'<span>'.$grade.'</span>'.'</li>';
}
?>
</ul>
```

What I cant figure out is to make the list element clickable and when you click it all of the values in content_array should be displayed and the list should dissapear, still same page (index.php) but if you click first list-element it should be `index.php?page=first` and second list-element should be  `index.php?page=second` and so on... I figure I should use `$_GET['page']` somehow but I dont know much PHP so if someone could point me in the right direction or know any online manual for it i would be happy!

Comment: Can you show us how the demo.txt looks like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<ul id="list">
<?php 
for($i = 0; $i < count($content_array); $i++){
  $values = explode(';', $content_array[$i]);
  $titel = $values[0];
  $grade = $values[1];
  $link = $values[2];
  $pic = $values[3];
  $desc = $values[4];            
  echo '<li>';
  echo '<a href="index.php?page=' . $i . '">';
  echo $titel.'<span>'.$grade.'</span>';
  echo '</a>';
  echo '</li>';
}
?>
</ul>
```

Use this to check which page:

```
<?php
  $page = $_GET['page'];
  if($page === '0') {
      //Do what you want for the first page
  }
?>
```

Comment: but how do I apply that to the loop, it needs to be conected to the list element somehow?

Comment: Edited answer with a better example.

Comment: the <a>-tag should be inside of the <li>-tag.

Comment: ok but lets say I create three listelements doesnt all three of them have the '<a href="index.php?page=first">'

Comment: First page would be 0. I'm not trying to be rude, I just realised that wasn't obvious.